# Celery dockerfile

Tags: python, django, celery

I'm using Django and celery together in an app(or container) but I want to separate celery in another app(or container). I am not sure how should I do this because my tasks are in the Django app.
so how should I set celery parameters in order to access tasks?

Answer (score 0):

you should create different container in docker-compose.yml like this:

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  proj_container:
      build: .
      image: backend
      container_name: proj_container
      command: sh -c "python3 manage.py makemigrations --no-input app && python3 manage.py migrate && python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
      restart: always
      ports:
        - 8000:8000
      volumes:
        - .:/your_proj
      depends_on:
        - rabbitmq
rabbitmq:
      image: rabbitmq:3.11-alpine
      container_name: rabbitmq
      ports:
        - "5672:5672"
      restart: on-failure

  celery:
      build: .
      container_name: celery
      command: celery -A your_proj_name worker -l info
      volumes:
        - .:/your_proj
      env_file:
        - ./.env
      depends_on:
        - proj_container
        - rabbitmq

  celery-beat:
      build: .
      container_name: celery_beat
      command: celery -A your_proj_name beat -l info
      volumes:
        - .:/your_proj
      depends_on:
        - proj_container
        - rabbitmq
```

rabbitmq was my celery broker and I also create a container for that...

Comment: thanks. but I can't use docker-compose (I'm using Kubernetes)